# Map containing Objects not working as expected Scala

Tags: scala, object, dictionary

Trying to understand basic Scala concepts. Why is this code not compiling ?

```
 case class User(
               id: Int,
               firstName: String,
               lastName: String,
               age: Int,
               gender: Option[String])

object UserRepository {
 val users = Map
 ( 1 ->  User(1, "John", "Doe", 32, Some("male")),
   2 -> User(2, "Johanna", "Doe", 30, None)
   )
//def findById(id: Int): Option[User] = users
//def findAll = users.values
def getUsers() = { users }
}

for ((k,v) <- UserRepository.getUsers() ){
 println(v)
}
```

Error:(25, 42) value filter is not a member of object cala.collection.immutable.Map
    for ((k,v) <- UserRepository.getUsers() ){

I expected that val users is holding Map ?

Simple map is working fine:

```
val simpleMap = Map (1 -> "First", 2 -> "Second")

for ((k,v) <- simpleMap ){
 println(v)
}
```

Comment: When running into error messages that I don't fully understand, it helps to explicitly note the return type of a `val`, `def`, etc. In your case you could explicitly note: `def getUsers(): Map[Int, User] = ...`.

Comment: A tried that, and it was not working - coming from Java world didn't expect, that new line cloud mean so much. What is the meaning of second expression ?

Comment: `What is the meaning of second expression ?` Could you please say more? Maybe Alexey answered your question already with his posted answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
val users = Map
( 1 ->  User(1, "John", "Doe", 32, Some("male")),
  2 -> User(2, "Johanna", "Doe", 30, None)
)
```

This is two separate expressions: first you do `val users = Map` (which is valid in Scala, and assigns the *companion object* of type `Map` to `users`), then evaluate

```
( 1 ->  User(1, "John", "Doe", 32, Some("male")),
  2 -> User(2, "Johanna", "Doe", 30, None)
)
```

and throw away the result. If you tell the compiler the definition isn't over yet by moving `(` to the line above, it'll work:

```
val users = Map(
  1 ->  User(1, "John", "Doe", 32, Some("male")),
  2 -> User(2, "Johanna", "Doe", 30, None)
)
```

Comment: I miss ; soooo much :) ! Tnx

Comment: What is the meaning of this second evaluation?

Comment: Do you mean the second expression in the original example (i.e. `(1 -> ...)`)? It'll return a tuple of two tuples and then throw the result away, since it isn't assigned to anything. (Scala will give you a warning if you throw away the result of `1 + 1` like this, but unfortunately not in this case, because tuple creation is really a constructor call and it could have side effects.)

Answer (score 2):

Start parenthesis immediately after Map to tell scala compiler that parenthesis belongs to Map

Instead of this

```
object UserRepository {
 val users = Map
 ( 1 ->  User(1, "John", "Doe", 32, Some("male")),
   2 -> User(2, "Johanna", "Doe", 30, None)
   )
//def findById(id: Int): Option[User] = users
//def findAll = users.values
def getUsers() = { users }
}
```

do this

```
object UserRepository {
   val users = Map( 1 ->  User(1, "John", "Doe", 32, Some("male")),
     2 -> User(2, "Johanna", "Doe", 30, None)) //start parenthesis after Map
   //def findById(id: Int): Option[User] = users
   //def findAll = users.values
  def getUsers() = { users }
}
```